# what is the equivalent for ajaxComplete if I use a xhr request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-ajax

I'm working in an app and I was catching all the ajax request using:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (xhr, status) {
        //...
});
```

Now, I'm using `MicrosoftMvcAjax` and `MicrosoftAjax` and when a XHR request finished a message in the console says: `XHR finished loading`.

How I can catch when a `xhr` request finish or what is the equivalent for `ajaxComplete` in `xhr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counters

```
var _complete = 0, _on = 0;

function incr(){ _on++; }
function comp(){ _complete++; if(_complete==_on) console.log("All the completed")}

// Now use these function wherever you want to make an AJAX Call like

incr();
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    comp();
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```